# Google Maps Android API v2, wrong marker place

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have some code to display a Google map for the location (36.1302,5.524) with a marker at this location. I create the marker with this location, the problems is that the marker shows up in the wrong place.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude,mLongitude);
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("I am here!");
    googleMap.addMarker(options);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}
```

here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V10iS.jpg

Comment: I think your question is not completed.

Comment: I used Google Api to get the user location, then i want to display it on the map using Google Maps Api, the problem is i get the correct location data but when i add the marker it place it on the wrong place like i am showing in the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `mLatitude` and `mLongitude` values are probably 0 and the location plotted on the map is `0,0`.

This is mostly because you are using `mLatitude` and `mLongitude` variables before their values are set. This is happening because `onMap` ready is called pretty early on in an activity lifecycle while getting coordinates from a sensor takes some time.

Try adding marker in `onLocationChanged(Location location)` callback method.